# Why can't I use execute() for an array?

Tags: php, arrays, execute

I'm trying to implement a verification email process to my website but I got an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   bool in :56 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in on line 56

Here is my code:

```
      $user_activation_code = md5(rand());

  // Nuevo Usuario
  $hashed = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $insert_query = 'INSERT INTO clientes (full_name,email,user_activation_code,user_email_status,password,permissions,street,numero,interior,city,state,zip_code,country) VALUES ("$name","$email","$user_activation_code",:user_email_status,"$hashed",cliente,"$street","$numero","$interior","$city","$state","$zip_code",Mexico)';
  $statement = $db->prepare($insert_query);
  $statement -> execute(
    array(
      'full_name'            => $_POST['name'],
      'email'                => $_POST['email'],
      'password'             => $hashed,
      'user_activation_code' => $user_activation_code,
      ':user_email_status'    => 'no verificado'
    )
  );
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Your query failed, use error reporting to see why. An array is valid with PDO so that isn't the issue. All values should be being bound, not just some of them. I would guess `Mexico` is your current issue though

Comment: If you're going to prepare your statement, you might as well bind all of the parameters. It will save you headaches down the road.

Comment: Looking at this again I think you're mistaken. You don't have a `password` placeholder. `"$hashed"` should be `:password` in your query (in the `values()` part).

Comment: You don't create array entries for your column names, you create them for your bind names. I.e., you are trying to bind `full_name`, `email`, `password`, and `user_activation_code` but you have no `:full_name`, `:email`, `:password`, or `:user_activation_code` in your query.

Comment: So... your `prepare` failed.

Comment: If you are using `PDO`, you should do `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` before your `prepare` function. This will cause `prepare` to throw an exception and let you know why `prepare` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to properly bind your array to the query.

PDO for using an associative array you need to have the values in both the query string and the same values in your key.

```
$insert_query = 'INSERT INTO clientes (full_name,email,user_activation_code,user_email_status,password,permissions,street,numero,interior,city,state,zip_code,country) VALUES (:full_name,:email,:user_activation_code,:user_email_status,:password,"cliente","$street","$numero","$interior","$city","$state","$zip_code","Mexico")';
array(
  ':full_name'            => $_POST['name'],
  ':email'                => $_POST['email'],
  ':password'             => $hashed,
  ':user_activation_code' => $user_activation_code,
  ':user_email_status'    => 'no verificado'
)
```

Please also bind your other values such as: $city, $state etc.

Comment: You put the bind placeholders in the column list, they should be in the value list.

Comment: @AlexHowansky nice catch

Comment: `Mexico` and `cliente` likely will still cause issues, and really all the values should be bound. Any could contain a quote and this would again break.